# Solve the limit by epsilon and delta $\lim\limits_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ y\to 0}}\frac{2x-3y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+ y^{2}}} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ y\to 0}}\frac{2x-3y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+ y^{2}}} = 0$

I´m trying to prove this limit by its definition. How can I get a bound for $\left|\frac{2x-3y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+ y^{2}}}\right|$ if know that the bottom part is bounded by $\delta$?

Comment: This is not true, at least if by $\lim_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ y\to 0}}$ you mean $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}$. It's easy to see if you take, for example, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, $y_n=0$. You have $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2x_n-3y_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2}} = 2$$ It can be proven that if you take other sequences, you can get any result from $-\sqrt{13}$ to $\sqrt{13}$. This function has no limit at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limit does not exist. Check that setting $x=3t$, and $y=4t$, letting $t \to 0$  gives a limit of $-6/5$ but if you set $x=3t$ and $y=-4t$ instead, then the limit is $18/5$.